# Can't record screen on Yosemite with quickTime Player

Tags: screen-capture, quicktime

I'm trying to do a screen recording, but I'm having issues with quickTime player. Every time I press the record button and then click on my screen to record, it starts recording for a second and then results in the message:

> **QuickTime Player quit unexpectedly.**
>
> Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.

As you can see here:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you out of storage on your HD?

Comment: Nope, I actually have 200GB available.

Answer (score 1):

Try repairing the disk permissions. Go to Disk Utility, select your HD and then click Repair and select Repair Disk Permissions. Hopefully, this will solve your problem. Allot around twenty minutes for the process.